# Multiple buttons to control popups individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, dynamic

I found this code while looking for a way to create popups and it does work but I am trying to figure out how make it work with multiple dynamically created divs.

```
function popupOpenClose(popup) {

/* Add div inside popup for layout if one doesn't exist */
if ($(".wrapper").length == 0){
    $(popup).wrapInner("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
}

/* Open popup */
$(popup).show();

/* Close popup if user clicks on background */
$(popup).click(function(e) {
    if ( e.target == this ) {
        if ($(popup).is(':visible')) {
            $(popup).hide();
        }
    }
});

/* Close popup and remove errors if user clicks on cancel or close buttons */
$(popup).find("button[name=close]").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".formElementError").is(':visible')) {
        $(".formElementError").remove();
    }
    $(popup).hide();
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-js=open]").on("click", function() {
        popupOpenClose($(".popup"));
    });
});
```

I would like to be able to use multiple buttons to control individual divs such as a button with id "pop1" will open the div "popup1" and button with id "pop2" will open div with id "popup2" etc.

```
<button id="pop1">Open popup</button>
<button id="pop2">Open popup</button>

<div id="popup1" class="popup">
    <h2>This is my popup 1</h2>
    <button name="close">Close popup</button>
</div>
<div id="popup2" class="popup">
    <h2>This is my popup2</h2>
    <button name="close">Close popup</button>
</div>
```

I create the buttons and divs dynamically with php so there is no set amount and I would like to make sure that they all work no matter how many are generated. For each new div it increments the number on the id like you can see above.

I tried doing this but the buttons will print everything in all available divs because I am not targeting them individually. I can't figure that part out.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button[id*=pop]").on("click", function() {
        popupOpenClose("[id*=popup]");
    });
});
```

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can I see your dynamically adding div code as well??

Comment: Its just a foreach loop. basically $increment = $increment++; foreach ($buttonDiv as $data){ echo '<button id="pop' . $increment . '">button</button>'; echo '<div id="popup' . $increment . '"> stuff </div>';

Comment: Sorry that is just a quick sloppy type up. Im just pulling values from mysql and throwing an increment in on the ids

Comment: Its okay,So your trying to add those div in run time after page is loaded,Is that right?

Comment: I am just trying to figure out how to have button 1 target div 1 and button 2 target div 2 etc whatever way I can. So if I have 20 buttons and 20 divs I want each one button to control the matching div. button id="1" makes div id"1" popup etc. Here is the original code that I found. I am just trying to alter it tow work for me. https://codepen.io/rachel_web/pen/YXMEqO

Answer (score 0):

I have made some change on your html as it would be easy to get element this way

```
<button id="pop_1" class="btnpopUpOpen">Open popup</button>
<button id="pop_2" class="btnpopUpOpen">Open popup</button>

<div id="popup_1" class="popup">
<h2>This is my popup 1</h2>
<button name="close">Close popup</button>
</div>
<div id="popup_2" class="popup">
   <h2>This is my popup2</h2>
<button name="close">Close popup</button>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$("button.btnpopUpOpen").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var myID=$(this).prop('id').split('_')[1];
 popupOpenClose('div.popup_'+myID);
});

$("form button[name=close]").off().on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 if ($(".formElementError").is(':visible')) {
    $(".formElementError").remove();
}
$(this).parent().hide();
});
```

**Note: If your are trying to add div dynamically after page is loaded.Make sure to re-register your event as well**

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, not sure why, I don't know a whole lot about javascript. I'll just try to go over it more later in awhile and try to figure it out. Thanks a lot for trying to help.

Comment: It should be working at least logic wise..if possible try to send the entire code and i'll look it up for you...